# Adding instances of Mesh to array isn't working

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create several duplicates of a mesh randomly distributed around my THREE.Js scene. I've used the clone() method in a for loop to do so. The array shows a list of the clones I created in the console, but when I try to call the individual elements of the array, I get undefined returned to me in the console. This is the code I tried:

```
let ball = new THREE.Mesh();
loader.load( './ball.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    gltf.scene.traverse(function(model) { //for gltf shadows!
        if (model.isMesh) {
          model.castShadow = true;
          model.material = sphereMaterial;
        }
    });
    ball = gltf.scene
    
    scene.add( ball );

    for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        let newBall = ball.clone()
        scene.add(newBall)
        newBall.position.set(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) * 2 - 10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) * 3 - 10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) * 2 - 10)
        pos_arr.push(newBall)
    }
    
}, undefined, function ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
} );
```

This is what I get when I call `console.log(pos_arr)` :

[image]

Then, if I were to call, say `console.log(pos_arr[2])`, I would get `undefined`.

By any chance, does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The usual root cause of this issue is that you access `pos_arr` too early. Meaning before the `onLoad()` callback of `GLTFLoader` has been executed.

There are various ways to fix this issue and the solution mainly depends on how you have structured your app. One approach that can always be used is to pass an instance of [LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager) to all of your loaders and use its `onLoad()` callback to finish your scene setup or start object access.

Comment: Hi, by any chance, what does passing an instance of LoadingManager to all of the loaders look like? I tried look it up, but I couldn't find a concrete answer.

Comment: The link documentation page shows an examples how to pass an instance of `LoadingManager` to `GLTFLoader`.